# Simulate No Flash in Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, linux, flash, debugging, ubuntu

I've searched this and cannot find it. I've tried different plugins and different browsers (Firefox, Opera, and Chrome). I've tried most of the no flash plugins for each of those as well as disabling Flash plugins/addons in the settings. I *also* renamed the `.so` file in `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/` i found by searching the system. when i renamed it, makes Firefox and Chrome ask to install Flash, but *still*:

```
alert(navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'].type);
```

returns:

```
application/x-shockwave-flash
```

I'm not sure what else to try without uninstalling Flash, but that will be a total pain in the ass for this. I also REALLY don't want to use SWFObject just to see if Flash is at all installed which I can do simply with:

```
if(navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Chrome makes this super easy if you go to:

chrome://plugins/

From there you can enable/disable all of your plugins. Then restart the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you deployed your site yet? If so, you can just punch the URL into [Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/), set Flash to disabled and then preview your site.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, try to disable the Shockwave Flash plugin.

You can find this screen in "Tools > Plugin config." or "Tools > extensions > plugins" or something like that, my FF are in french... :p

Comment: I don't even have that anymore since i renamed the .so file :(

Comment: re-install the plugin or rename the old .so file then restart Firefox :D

Comment: I did, it's renamed and Firefox can't find the plugin and asks to "Install Missing Plugins" after restarting, but the JS code I pasted above (the alert code) still returns "application/x-shockwave-flash" as if it were installed.